# Nullable runtime crash after lint improvement

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Here's my code in Room.kt

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM databaseaugmentedskudetails WHERE sku = :sku")
fun getById(sku: String): DatabaseAugmentedSkuDetails
```

```
val result = getById(sku)
var canPurchase = if (result == null) true else result.canPurchase. // lint warns result == null is always false but in reality it can be null returned by dao
```

Above line was translated to Java as below

```
boolean canPurchase = result == null ? true : result.getCanPurchase();
```

Everything works fine until lint changed my kotlin code to

```
var canPurchase = result?.canPurchase ?: true // lint warns safe call is unnecessary for non-null type
```

which got translated to Java code as below

```
boolean canPurchase = result != null ? result.getCanPurchase() : null;
```

I then get the following crash during runtime from time to time

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
```

I'd assume lint should be smart enough not to break my code.

My question is,

why is `result?.canPurchase ?: true` translated to `result != null ? result.getCanPurchase() : null`? Shouldn't `true` be returned instead of `null`?

Comment: Kotlin compiler is smart, if it sees the object can never be nullable then elvis operator has no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function declaration must make the return type nullable in order to make Kotlin know that the function could eventually return nullable type.

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM databaseaugmentedskudetails WHERE sku = :sku")
fun getById(sku: String): DatabaseAugmentedSkuDetails? // <- ? here
```